# How to generate fake data for cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1

Hi I need to generate fake data for [cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/)
about 100 000 000 row so i tried to generate .csv file with 1 000 000 row
and then import that in db 100 time, but there is a problem when I use COPY
operator I must have all uuid, so using COPY isn't way, also I thing generate those record by user-defined but I'm not sure It will be worked.

May be someone have had issue like that and solve it, please help.

Comment: what schema are you trying to generate fake data for?

Comment: schema is a simple like mysql table with some fields and data, in general schema not very important I'd like know way which generate data will take not very long time

Comment: The schema is important, the csv you create for example needs to be reflect the cells of the table

Comment: have you looked into using `cassandra-stress` ? You can have a user defined profile with custom format

Comment: Thank you, I think the `cassandra-stress` tool is exactly what i wanted